# How to get value outside typescript subscribe function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following subscribe function for some service.

```
this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
this.id = params['id'];
this._someService
      .thisById(this.id)
      .subscribe(value => {
         this.valueObj = value; 
     });
});
```

This seems all right. Except that I need to use the ***this.valueObj*** in the following functions outside the subscribe function.

```
private  _checkOpeningHours(data: any): string {
    const curDayName = this._getDayName();
    const todaysOpeningData = ***this.valueObj***.openHours[curDayName];

    if (!todaysOpeningData) return "ERROR!";
    if (!todaysOpeningData.status) return `IT'S ${curDayName.toUpperCase()} - WE ARE CLOSED TODAY!`;

    return `IT'S ${curDayName.toUpperCase()}, ${new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' })} - ${this._isOpen(todaysOpeningData) ? 'WE ARE OPEN' : 'SORRY, WE ARE CLOSED'}!`;

  }

  private _refresh() {
    this.opening = this._checkOpeningHours(***this.valueObj***.openHours[this._getDayName()]);

    setTimeout(() => this._refresh(), 60 * 1000);
  }
```

How can I get these functions to work with the ***this.valueObj***?

Comment: I don't know much about angular but I remember that it uses a lot of dependency injection. Can you add a parameter with matching name to the method so that angular injects the value?

Comment: are you sure that it's not an issue with the thisById function being asynchronous and that you are calling the other function before thisById returns?

Comment: where are the `_checkOpeningHours` and `_refresh` functions defined? it's not in the same class as the other code? pls add some more context

Comment: @toskv thisById() function is async which is what it is suppose to be.

Comment: @lenny In the same class, but as I know subscribe() functions won't let their variable values to be use outside the subscribe() function.

Comment: then how are the 2 being called? what's the time relation between the 2 of them? :)

Comment: you are using `this` to access **valueObj**, so I assume that it's a class member. you should be able to use it like you already do in your functions. Did you try it? What is the error?

Comment: @ObasiObenyOj he seems to be saving the result as a class property. There's no problem using that later from anywhere in the class, if the value is initialized.

Comment: @toskv this._refresh() is called in the ngOnInit(). And this_refresh() can be called inside the subscribe function which it will all work find. But the _checkOpeningHours() will still need the this.valueObj to get {{opening}}

Comment: @lenny I tried it, but this.valueObj outside the subscribe() function can't be used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Async calls need to be properly chained.

If you return an observable (requires `map` instead of `subscribe`)

```
someMethod() {
  this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.id = params['id'];
  return this._someService
      .thisById(this.id)
      .map(value => {
         return this.valueObj = value; 
     });
  });
}
```

then you can use it like

```
private  _checkOpeningHours(data: any): string {
  this.someMethod().subscribe(val => {
    console.log(val); // here the value is available
  });
}
```

Without proper chaining it's very likely that `_checkOpeningHours()` accesses `this.valueObj` looong before the value becomes available.

Comment: For some reason I get this TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Comment: Did you add the `return` to `return this._someService`?

Comment: I also forgot a `return` inside `map` (necessary because of `{}`) - fixed.

Comment: I thought is the second `return` but when I add it I get the TypeError: this.someMethod(...).subscribe is not a function

Comment: I don't know how your code is organized because the context is missing in your question. My answer assumes that `someMethod` and `_checkOpeningHours` are inside the same class.

Comment: You are right. All is in the same class.` Error:: in sublime ( property subscribe does not exist on type subscription`. Whatever that means.

Comment: I guess you have still `subscribe` instead of `map` in `someMethod`.

Comment: `this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
     this.id = params['id'];
     // Retrieve Pet with Id route param
     return this._placesService
        .findPetById(this.id)
        .map(value => {
           return value; 
       });
    });` that's my code. ***TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined***

Comment: Sorry, I misread your first lines of code because it's not properly indented. I think you should just call your `someMethod` from within `this.route.params.subscribe(...)` and be fine.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer code so I get an understanding of what you mean. Thanks

Comment: It would be easier if you would first make more clear what you actually try to accomplish. Where do you have the first code block? Where is `_checkOpeningHours` being called from?

Comment: From my question above, `_checkOpeningHours` is being called inside _refresh function. But `_checkOpeningHours` needs the `this.valueObj` to run.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to just use `setTimeout(() => this.valueObj ? this._refresh() : () => {}, 60 * 1000);`? to not execute `_refresh` when `valueObj` is not yet available?

Comment: I can't figure away for that to be enough since I need to  get opening time for today with current day name in the `_checkOpeningHours` . If there is a way for that I will go for it.

Comment: I see. Then just return `null` or something from `_checkOpeningHours` when `this.valueObj` is not yet available.