# How to access variable value outside subscribe method so that the variable can be used in service method's return in angular 10 using typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

```
 getProductbyFilter(filter: filterDataModel): Observable<any> {
  this.stringtoArrayService.convertStringtoArray(some string input).subscribe(productUserResponse => {
  if (productUserResponse) {
    this.userProfileProduct = productUserResponse;
    this.newParams = this.userProfileProduct[0].Function_Network;
    if (this.newParams != null) {
      this.updatedStr = this.newParams.replace('&', '__', this.newParams);
    } else {
      this.updatedStr = this.userProfileProduct[0].Function_Network;
    }
  }
});
  return this.http.post(url + this.updatedStr, filter, httpOptions);}
```

I have already visited these links they said to use method inside subscribe. I want to access this.updatedStr but it's returning undefined. I can't write return inside subscribe also. Can anyone please help?

1. [assigning variable outside subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55916555/assigning-value-to-variable-within-subscribe-method-is-not-set-outside-of-the-su)
2. [how-to-get-value-outside-typescript-subscribe-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285965/how-to-get-value-outside-typescript-subscribe-function)

Comment: So after setting `updatedStr` in subscribe,  you want to call other api with using `updatedStr`

Comment: yes i want to use updatedStr for another api call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.. I have not tested it though.

```
setUpdatedStr(productUserResponse){
  if (productUserResponse) {
    this.userProfileProduct = productUserResponse;
    this.newParams = this.userProfileProduct[0].Function_Network;
    if (this.newParams != null) {
      this.updatedStr = this.newParams.replace('&', '__', this.newParams);
    } else {
      this.updatedStr = this.userProfileProduct[0].Function_Network;
    }
  }
}

getProductbyFilter(filter: filterDataModel): Observable<any> {
 return this.stringtoArrayService.convertStringtoArray(some string input).pipe(
  tap(productUserResponse => this.setUpdatedStr(productUserResponse)),
  switchMap(_=>callAfterSetUpdaterStr(filter))
);

callAfterSetUpdaterStr(filter: filterDataModel): Observable<any>{
  // set httpOptions and url
  return this.http.post(url + this.updatedStr, filter, httpOptions);
}
```

Comment: getProductByFilter(): Observable<any>{  }..also dont forget to import Observable, switchMap, tap from rxjs.copy answer properly...also `callAfterSetUpdaterStr(filter: filterDataModel): Observable<any>` use properly

Comment: switchMap gets response from `stringToArrayService` like.`tap(productUserResponse)` gets. But we don't need it in switchMap so we used _. It's like there is input to switchMap but we won't use it. You can upvote answer if you thinks it's valuable

Comment: Thank you for your explanation it is really helpful and valuable.. I can't upvote yet i need minimum 15 reputation to cast a vote.. But i marked your answer as accepted.. Thank you again!!!

Answer (score 0):

That is how JavaScript works

```
getProductbyFilter() {
  yourSubcriptionThatSetsUpdatedStr();
  return yourStatementThatReturnHttpCallObs();
}
```

`yourSubcriptionThatSetsUpdatedStr` is independent of `yourStatementThatReturnHttpCallObs`. So that javascript will finish `yourStatementThatReturnHttpCallObs` before `yourSubcriptionThatSetsUpdatedStr`

which means `this.updatedStr` is returned even before it gets assigned a value from `yourSubcriptionThatSetsUpdatedStr`; that makes `this.updatedStr` an undefined.

use **Promise** or **Async/Await** to make `yourStatementThatReturnHttpCallObs`wait for `yourSubcriptionThatSetsUpdatedStr`to finish.

so that you can return from initial method;

Comment: Thank you!!  but in my project promise/async/await is not used actually..